# Remote Desktop Connection with Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: server, 13.10, remote-desktop

I had a PC running Ubuntu Server 12.04 and RDC was working fine but when I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 when I go to connect I just get a grey screen. I would like to just be able to login and use the terminal, so I don't want to use xfce. Is there anyway I can do this on 13.10?

Comment: I get the same issue, and I also do not want to use XFCE. When will there be a fix?

Comment: BTW it's not just Win 7, it's any RDP to Ubuntu 13.10 (Desktop/Server/X11 etc). I suggest you remove the "Server" and "Win 7" from your title as this would just confuse people. Server is generally terminal only, and Win 7 suggests the problem is related to only win 7 users. I have 2 ubuntu machines and I can't remote from one to the other. It's a real downer.

Comment: I ended up just going back to Ubunutu Server 12.04, and I will remove the Win 7 part from the total but I mean specifically Ubuntu Server, with the terminal only even it is a problem with the desktop version too but I was lookin for a fix for the server.